# How to pass arguments to self-contained .NET Core console app on Debian

Tags: c#, .net-core, debian, self-contained

I built self-contained .NET Core console app on Debian, but I want to pass some arguments on startup. For example `./myapp --value`, something like this. Problem is, in `string[] args` nothing is appearing on Debian. On Windows it's working normally.

If it's important, I'm using Debian 10 with XFCE (with xfce4-terminal).

What should I do to pass arguments correctly?

Comment: It works the same way on Linux as on Windows. If you are copy/pasting maybe you have an unexpected line return, try typing it out manually.  If you are typing it out just like you have above, then I've got nothing sorry. It works for me.

Comment: @Sean I created test project to print arguments only and pass some arguments... and it works on it! Weird issue, both projects are on .NET Core 3.1 and I'm building them the same way. I don't know, what is the problem here. And yeah, I'm typing it manually. Anyway, thanks for answering.
Oh, I forgot. My project was converted from .NET Framework 4.8 earlier. Maybe this is the reason of this weird behaviour?